# How does Flask-WTF use methods defined in a form?

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

When creating a form using `Flask-WTF` and implementing a method, say, to check whether a username is available, I'm curious to how/why such methods work.

What I mean is, not once do you reference any of methods defined in the form class throughout the rest of your code; they seem to work on their own without any interference - can somebody explains how and why it works this way?

For example:

```
class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired()])
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    ...

def validate_username(self, username):
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=username.data).first()
        if user is not None:
            raise ValidationError('Please use a different username.')
```

The above code seems to run `validate_username` on submission of the form without myself having to call it.

Answer (score 0):

This is by convention - when your form is being validated,  it will check whether you have defined any custom [inline validators](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/forms/#inline-validators) in the form of `validate_your_field` and run these.

You can find more details in the [Custom Validators](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/validators/#custom-validators) section of documentation.